# ASP.NET Core set Cookie Name

Tags: cookies, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a solution with two ASP.NET Core apps, lets call web1 and web2. They use IdentityServer4 as centralize authentication/authorization. I am setting the cookie name with

```
...
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "web";
}) 
...
```

Can I set a common name for both apps or each app should have its own cookie name, for example web1 and web 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is basically it's up to you, but you probably should not set cookie same because if both your apps are hosted on the same domain and subdomain, it will cause issues with the authentication middleware especially if your web apps require different scopes for different resources in their `access_token` as you would essentially be sharing that cookie between apps.

TLDR: Don't have same cookie name for different web apps unless you intend sharing that cookie between web apps.

Comment: I thought about it, I was looking for another opinion. Thanks :-)